# Selection of unique records by one field

Tags: php, laravel-5, query-builder, laravel-5.8

I need to select only entries with unique values 'who_id'. But in this case, I get all the records.

```php
$history_today = DB::table('view_history')
    ->select('girl_id', 'who_id', 'girls.name as name', 'girls.main_image', 
        'view_history.time', 'girls.age', 'cities.name as city_name', 
        'girls.city_id')
    ->where('girl_id', $girl->id)
    ->where('who_id', '!=', null)
    ->where('who_id', '!=', $girl->id)
    ->leftJoin('girls', 'girls.id', '=', 'view_history.who_id')
    ->leftJoin('cities', 'girls.city_id', '=', 'cities.id_city')
    ->orderBy('time', 'DESC')
    ->distinct('who_id')
    ->paginate(15);
```